# How do I redirect to another webpage using laravel?

Tags: laravel

I am trying to redirect to another page but unfortunately, it's not working How can I redirect from one page to another page please help me thanks.

Database table

```
Navigation table 
https://ibb.co/9tBqVpr
```

HTML view

```
@foreach($Navigation as $Navi)
    <li class="nav-item ">
        <a class="nav-link " href="{{$Navi->slug}}">{{$Navi->Nav_menu}}</a>
    </li>
@endforeach
```

controller

```
public function whatwedo()
{
    $data=([
            'Navigation'=>Navigations::where('slug',$slug)->first(),
          ]);
    return view('front_end.what_we_do',$data);
}
```

**ROUTE**

```
Route::get('/','HomeController@index');
Route::get('whatwedo','HomeController@whatwedo');
Route::get('testimonal','HomeController@testimonal');
Route::get('product','HomeController@product');
Route::get('contact_us','HomeController@contact_us');
```

Comment: from `whatwedo()` function you want redirect which function or which route ?

Comment: I want to redirect from whatwedo page to testimonal  page .

Comment: yes can you show your `testimonal()` and if you return any view show that also ?

Comment: can you give me an example a/c to my code thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
return redirect()->route('route.name', [$param]);
```

Reference:
[Laravel -> HTTP Redirects](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
redirect(url('route_name'));
```

or

```
return Redirect::route('route_name')->with( ['data' => $data] );
```

Answer (score 0):

I this you have to use consider basics in **Laravel**

Use **Blade** view not a **HTML** and use **url()** or **route()** and

use different slug for all routes as per your route is not going to work

```
@foreach($Navigation as $Navi)
   <li class="nav-item ">
      a class="nav-link " href="{{ url('testimonal/'.$Navi->slug)}}">{{$Navi->Nav_menu}}</a>
   </li>
@endforeach
```

if use you function like this

```
public function testimonal($slug)
   {
       $data = Navigations::where('slug',$slug)->first();
       return view('front_end.testimonial',['data'=>$data]);
   }

    Route::get('testimonal/{sulg}','HomeController@testimonal');
```

and if you have plan to redirect this route from another function like you did

```
public function whatwedo($slug)
{
  $data = Navigations::where('slug',$slug)->first();
  return redirect('testimonal')->with(['data'=>$data]);
}
```